# Proofing Sequence $0<x_nr^n C$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Let $x_n$ be sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that $\lim (x_{n+1}/x_n) < 1$. Show that for some $r$ with $0<r<1$ and for some $C>0$ then we have $0<x_n<Cr^n$ for all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Use this to show that $\lim (x_n) =0$.

This problem appear in The Element of Real Analysis book.
I know that this must be related to theorem which said that:
(1) $\lim (a_n)=0$ and
(2) $||x_n -x||<c|a_n|$ for some $C>0$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $\lim (x_n)=x$.

But I don't know what the first I should do. can anyone explain about this problem?

Comment: Get $x_{n+1}<rx_n$ (for $n$ large ) and use induction.

Comment: i can't get the idea, if we proof $x_{n+1} <rx_n$ then what should I do?

Comment: Can you get $x_{n+2} <r^{2}x_n$?